# how to make google map user-friendly and responsive on web page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map on my webpage. it works completely fine but I am showing each country with some markers. it shows fine when window width is bigger than `577px`. but when window is ( window.innerWidth<577 ) half of my map is not showing.(users should scroll the map to visit all the markers) is there any way  I can show my map some how complete with all markers in small browsers?

here is my java-script code for google map

```
 if (typeof zoom === "undefined") {
    zoom = 12;
}
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: zoom,
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: center,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

I tried to change the zoom with adding this code on it

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
if (w < 577) {
  map.setZoom(5);
}
```

but the problem is that some markers are not showing any more,
Appreciate any help.

Comment: did you try setting the zoom, before generating the map? I mean, instead of doing `map.setZoom(5)`, doing `zoom = 5;`, before declaring the map

Comment: possible duplicate of [From an array of coordinates, how could I decide which to center the map on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158252/from-an-array-of-coordinates-how-could-i-decide-which-to-center-the-map-on)

Comment: i tried now. it has the same result. my map becomes smaller of-course and fine but some of the markers omitted. and when I click on the region I can visit all markers @MarceloOrigoni

Comment: @geocodezip that seems helpful but I am new to google map and completely confused with this one. I do not know what changes should I have in my codes? my problem is not to center one of the coordinates, the problem is that I need to show them all in small browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either one of two issues.

**1) Your map is too wide for the device you're viewing it on.**

You should set max-width: 100%; on the map element in your CSS

**2) The map is adjusting to the new device width but not re-centring**

Add each marker centre to a bounds object as they are created...

```
const oMap = new google.maps.Map(...);
const oBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for(...) {
    const oCentre = new google.maps.LatLng({
        lat: fLatitude,
        lng: fLongitude
    });

    const oMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: oCentre,
        map: oMap
    });

    oBounds.extend(oCentre);
}
```

Then re-centre the map when the device resizes...

```
window.addEventListener('resize', oEvent => {
    oMap.fitBounds(oBounds);
});
```